# Reference request about what ramification looks like etale locally

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ramification

Specifically, I'm looking for the proof of the following statement:

If $X\rightarrow Y$ is a finite map of degree $n$ of curves over $\mathbb{C}$, and $P\in X$ maps to $Q\in Y$ with degree of ramification $d$, then $X\times_Y\mathcal{O}_{Y,Q}^{sh}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,Q}^{sh}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i=1,...,\frac{n}{d}} Spec(\mathbb{C}[[x]]^{alg}[y]/(y-x^d))\rightarrow Spec(\mathbb{C}[[x]]^{alg})$, where $\mathbb{C}[[x]]^{alg}$ is the elements of $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ algebraic over $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

I remembered this being in Milne's "Etale Cohomology", but I must have been mistaken...

Comment: What do you mean by elements of $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$ ? Of course with your definition $\mathbb{C}[[x]]^{alg}=\mathbb C$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: This is equivalent to the statement that  the fraction field of Puiseux series (over $\mathbb{C}$) is algebraically closed.  I vaguely recall that there is a formulation close to yours in Qing Liu's book.

Comment: This is a special case of Abhyankar's lemma, which more generally computes the fundamental group of $R[1/x_1\ldots x_r]$ where $R$ is a strictly henselian local regular $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra and $x_1, \ldots, x_r$ are local parameters. See e.g. SGA1 Exp. XIII Appendix I, Prop. 5.2.